# Is Windows 8.1 shipped with barcode scanner?

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Do you know whether Windows 8.1 is shipped with a native/ built-in bar code scanner or do I need a 3rd party library for development?

Comment: No.  Buy one, read the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a [BarCodeScanner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.aspx) class available in Windows8.1 ( but not available in Windows 8)

There is a code sample also in MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.aspx

Comment: both urls are navigating to the same page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner.aspx

Comment: the code example is here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Barcode-scanner-sample-f39aa411

Answer (score 2):

No, Windows 8 doesn't have built in support for barcode recognition. There are some cheap libraries out there that you can buy. Also there are some open source projects.

We use [NeoDynamic Barcode](http://www.neodynamic.com/) at our workplace.

Here is piece of code from [How to read Barcode reader in windows 8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/93445a7c-07f8-4770-b1f4-00731d1e4f1b/how-to-read-barcode-reader-in-windows-8)

```
var ccu = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
ccu.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
ccu.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile x = await ccu.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
//FileOpenPicker fop = new FileOpenPicker();
//fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
//StorageFile x = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (x != null)
{
    ZXing.BarcodeReader br = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
    WriteableBitmap wrb;
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await x.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
         //fileStream.
         wrb = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(fileStream);
    }
var res = br.Decode(wrb);
testImage.Source = wrb;
//System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ISBN = " + res.ToString());
}
```

For complete reference: http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/discussions/393332

Note: please add references zxing.winrt and WriteableBitmapEx.WinRT from http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/